# Django - auto_now=True did not work for custom actions

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

My Model has the following field. It has to update whenever there is a change in that model.

modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

and I wrote a custom action to change the status of this model in the admin interface.

this particular field works fine for all kind of updates except the mentioned custom actions in the admin interface. Any ideas?

Comment: show us your custom action. is it a custom save()?

Comment: My Custom is given below.

def make_active(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(status='a')
make_active.short_description = "Mark selected Users as Active"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see in django's documentation that `update()` actually don't call `save()`. Thus, it's pretty normal that the DateField is not updated by `auto_now` (which updates on save() calls)

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-kwargs

Comment: Is there any other options to make it happen?

Comment: You can probably use update(status='a', modified_at=datetime.now) or something like this ?

Comment: You could manually send the save signal to trigger anything that uses that to run on a save.